# neo4j Loading CSV with Merge on specific property

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to input two CSV's with identical structures but different property values. I am trying to have it create only new nodes where the property 'name' does not match. What I think it is doing is that because the full column (which I am not using, is unique it is ignoring the MERGE and just creating a new node). My code looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://s3.amazonaws.com.../inputSample.csv' AS line
MERGE (e:Executable {system: line[0], location: line[1], name: line[2]})
MERGE (d:Dataset {system: line[3], group: line[4], name: line[5]})
CREATE (d)-[:input]->(e)

LOAD CSV FROM 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../sampleOutput.csv' AS line
MERGE (e:Executable {system: line[0], location: line[1], name: line[2]})
MERGE (d:Dataset {system: line[3], group: line[4], name: line[5]})
CREATE (e)-[:output]->(d)
```

A Sample line from the input:

```
A   Projects/bmp    bmp loc B   ACCT
```

A sample line from the Output:

```
B   Projects/asp    asp loc B   ACCT
```

So I dont want the second the second d:Dataset created in the secondary load because that information exists already is that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to MERGE nodes with 3 different values. So

```
(e:Executable {system: system1, location: location1, name: name1})
```

AND

```
(e:Executable {system: system1, location: location2, name: name1})
```

are different.

You should specify only one property on which to MERGE and SET the other properties afterwards :

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://s3.amazonaws.com.../inputSample.csv' AS line
MERGE (e:Executable {name: line[2]})
ON CREATE SET e.system = line[0], e.location = line[1]
MERGE (d:Dataset {name: line[5]})
ON CREATE SET e.system = line[3], d.location = line[4]
CREATE (d)-[:input]->(e)

LOAD CSV FROM 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../sampleOutput.csv' AS line
MERGE (e:Executable {name: line[2]})
ON CREATE SET e.system = line[0], e.location = line[1]
MERGE (d:Dataset {name: line[5]})
ON CREATE SET e.system = line[3], d.location = line[4]
CREATE (d)-[:input]->(e)
```

Comment: In your solution the only this is the last line should be CREATE (e)-[:output]->(d) other than that thanks!

Comment: True, copy paste issues, blame on me